# Regular Expression for (P) xxx-xxx-xxxx * (F) xxx-xxx-xxxx

Tags: regex

I'm new at this. Trying to match this format:

```
(P) xxx-xxx-xxxx • (F) xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

Tried this:

```
/^ \(([^P)])\) \d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4} \u2022 \(([^F)])\) \d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4} *$/
```

Doesn't match. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: What are the x characters actually?

Comment: Could you provide *real-life examples* of what should/shouldn't match?

Comment: Is the leading space in your regex there in your hypothetical input as well? Also, you are aware that `[^P]` matches *anything except `P`*? (And the same further on.)

Comment: what language are you?

Comment: The language is important.  Some languages (such as php) support the /u modifier to allow unicode chars.

Comment: I'm using Ruby. Sorry, not giving proper details. I'm supposed to match Phone number in the formant 123-234-7890 and Fax number in the format 234-456-7890

Answer (score 2):

To match this:

(P) xxx-xxx-xxxx • (F) xxx-xxx-xxxx       # Given x = 0-9

Try this:

^\(P\) (?:\d{3}-){2}\d{4} \u2022 \(F\) (?:\d{3}-){2}\d{4}$

It worked for me.

Comment: thats some serious regex

Comment: Thanks for the comments :) You can find some more serious regex at
http://www.talentcookie.com/2015/07/lets-practice-regular-expression/

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:
^(([P]) \d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4} \u2022)( ([F]) \d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})*$/

Thank you for the help!